# How do I get vim to autocomplete my jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, vim, plugins

I'm using vim to write my jQuery code. Is there a plugin that I can use to autocomplete parts of the code?

**Edit**

i found this Snippet for jquery [javascript-jquery Snippet](https://github.com/rogeliog/Vim-Snippets)

Comment: Not sure why the down votes. This seems like a reasonable question to me. Perhaps it could be worded better, but what is being asked seems clear to me. Is there a plugin for the vim editor that will allow standard code completion commands to work with common Javascript keywords/jQuery functions?

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is supported as part of vim's omni-completion languages. You can activate this completion via **Ctrl-x** + **Ctrl-o** when working inside a javascript buffer. For more info, type `:help new-omni-completion`
in the status bar.

I don't know of a plugin that specifically handles jQuery, but there are a few that trigger omni-completion as you type so it feels fairly native. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried YouCompleteMe combined with Tern for Vim? These work together to give you autocompletion but to get external library autocompletion you need to enable `eagerLoading` on new libs by setting the `eagerLoading` property within the `.tern-project` file.

A step by step guide on how to set this up can be found [here](http://www.theendian.com/blog/javascript-autocomplete-in-vim-for-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Snipmate. I recommend you to use [this version](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) instead of the one from vim.org which is no longer maintained (pay attention to the readme since this plugin requires some other).
Then you should try something like this [google search](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=snipmate+jquery&pbx=1&oq=snipmate+jquery&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1303l6047l0l6525l15l11l0l4l4l0l293l1589l0.4.4l8l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=980fac5185de01ec&biw=1433&bih=763).

If you don't find snippet that fit your need, then you could consider creating your own snippet file while coding. The syntax is very simple and powerful!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim) Tern support there is also the **Tern for Vim** Vim plugin which could be found here: https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim

Answer (score 0):

another way is coc-html with coc.nvim for html files, if you're editing javascript files there is no need, vim can auto complete jquery as long as it is npm/yarn installed in the project.