# Good Extension for vim to autocomplete HTML and/or CSS and possibly jquery?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, auto-close

I am using the vim console on windows.

Is there any good extension out there to autocmatically close HTML and/or CSS and possibly jquery tags?

like in eclipse when i got `<p` i press ctrl+space and it automatically puts me `<p> </p>`  ?

Comment: That's not auto completion, but auto-closing of tags, brackets, etc., and you'll find some information on the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim comes with an auto complete of `ctrl+p` and `ctrl+n`.

It is for the variables and functions you have written.

If you want to add support for tags and jQuery / JavaScript functions you might want to create a text file, write all of the functions you use and want (After all, most of us use a small subset of each library we utilize)  And then just load the file when an HTML file is created / loaded like so:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *`<extention>` badd `<dir to file>`
```

the extension in your case can be `.html` or `.js`

Edit: If you don't want to do it yourself, try this:
https://github.com/rogeliog/Vim-Snippets

And possibly read this question: [How do I get vim to autocomplete my jQuery code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990510/how-do-i-get-vim-to-autocomplete-my-jquery-code)

Edit2: If you want to have the autocomplete with `ctrl + space`, try this:

```
inoremap <expr> <C-Space> pumvisible() \|\| &omnifunc == '' ?
\ "\<lt>C-n>" :
\ "\<lt>C-x>\<lt>C-o><c-r>=pumvisible() ?" .
\ "\"\\<lt>c-n>\\<lt>c-p>\\<lt>c-n>\" :" .
\ "\" \\<lt>bs>\\<lt>C-n>\"\<CR>"
imap <C-@> <C-Space>
```

Comment: Added some more information about remapping the ctrl+p